# How to Identify the Python version in #! using environment variables

Tags: python, linux, interpreter

I have a problem which is caused by our encapsulated design.  Up till now lots of our scripts were written in bash and as a result the `#!/bin/bash` was always simple.

However now that we are rewriting our scripts in python that is a bit more difficult.  We deliver a specific version of python (to avoid version differences in client installed environments from breaking our implementation).  Because the specific version of python lives in a installed directory structure I need to route to it.

However I don't think the #! statement can accept environment variables from the shell that executes the file(tried and got a bad interpreter).

eg:

in `foo.py` I have `#!$dirloc/wherepythonlives/python`

In the bash shell I executed the file and got bad interpreter.
Is there a way of sneaking an environment variable into that `#!` line?

Or will I have to depend on an explicit path?  We want to support multiple versions of our software (which may mean multiple python versions) on one environment so I was hoping to somehow keep Python's `!#` statement inside the directory level we install into.

Comment: you could also write a sh script that just calls $dirloc/wherepythonlives/python foo.py rather than execute the script directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A common way to do this is to use the `env` program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

This will cause `env` to look along the `PATH` environment for a binary called `python`.

Comment: this worked after using a configuration file we have to alter the path variable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of being able to use environment variable in the shebang. You can use relative paths though

```
#! ../../usr/bin/python
```

edit:
You could always use env to specify to use a specific version. Then if that version can be found in $PATH it will be used otherwise the  script will fail

```
#! /usr/bin/env python2.7
```

Or you could make the entry point a generic script instead.

eg

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

if [[ $MYPYTHON ]]
then 
    $MYPYTHON main.py
else
    echo error message
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

The optimal solution to this dilemma is using distutils (setup.py, which creates correct *stubs* for you automatically, for a number of given "console entry points") and virtualenv (handling the "isolated multiple installations" part).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it all depends on how and in what environment your scripts will be invoked. You could call you scripts using `#!/usr/bin/env python`, which would allow you to control which python is used by manipulating the environment's `PATH`.

You could always specify a wrapper script as the interpreter, which runs a python executable relative to the script's location:

foo.py:

```
#!/bin/pyselector

import sys
sys.exit(0)
```

pyselector:

```
#!/bin/sh
SCRIPT_PATH="$(readlink -f $1)"
SCRIPT_DIR="$(dirname "$SCRIPT_PATH")"

"${SCRIPT_DIR}/my/local/python" "$@"
```